# express-handlebars unable to print Object content ,

Tags: express-handlebars

**express-handlebars**

```
exports.All_category = async (req,res)=>{
var categories = await Category.find({},{"date":0, '__v':0})
.then(result=> {
    console.log(result);
    res.render('category', { title: 'Category', cate: 'active',result });

})
```

I want to Print only name and id but its printing full Objects

[image: This is the result i an getting]

Comment: When i manually enter the data it shows the correct result but if i fetched data from Mongo DB its rendering like above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the whole object because the `model.find({});` method returns an object to **result** which you print afterwards.

So if you want to only print the id and the name then you should instead write:

```
console.log('Id: ' + result._id + ' Name: ' + result.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern , The issue happened because of @handlebars/allow-prototype-access

Answer (score 0):

TO add run time option in handle bar engine

app.engine('hbs', exphbs({layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts', extname: 'hbs',
defaultLayout:'layout'}));

the above mentions app engine that i created first then i added some runtime options

like this

app.engine('hbs', exphbs({layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts', extname: 'hbs',
defaultLayout:'layout',
runtimeOptions: {
allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true
}}));